# Get row where in one column there is a max value and in other column there is an exact value simultaneously

Tags: google-sheets

In this table I need to find the row where column `A` has exact value equal to `3` and in column `C` I have the `max` value. So in the image it is row number `16`, where Session Number is `15` (max) and Day is exactly `3`. And when I find this I need the value for the found row (`16`) and column `D`, i.e. value in `D16`. How can I do this?

EDIT:
[Here is the sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10syCPJh1upz-BxKZyJCJHn-eEFw180_x3NEYIh9HGqg/edit?usp=sharing) with Edit permission.

[image]

Comment: Where did you think to take the number 3 of your example? Or maybe it must be taken from the day of the month?

Comment: It is always more efficient for the volunteer contributors here when posters share a link to a spreadsheet containing their realistic sample data set. As it is, we don't even know what is in Column F. We have no starting data to work with unless we start a new sheet and enter it ourselves, no testing ground, etc. Help us to help you: share a link.

Comment: @Daniele this is just a simplified portion of my problem. Please don't focus on that particular value.

Comment: @ErikTyler Good point, thanks, here it is : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10syCPJh1upz-BxKZyJCJHn-eEFw180_x3NEYIh9HGqg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have left the following formula in your sheet (accounting for the fact that what you describe as Col F in your post is actually Col D in your sample spreadsheet):

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER(D:D,ROW(D:D)=VLOOKUP(MAX(FILTER(C:C,A:A=G2)),{C:C,ROW(C:C)},2,FALSE))))`

The search-key value in this case is entered in G2 (e.g., 3).

The inner `FILTER` will return only Col-C values where the Col-A value matches the search key in G2. (So if the search-key entered is 3, then this `FILTER` will return only the Col-C values where the Col-A value is also 3.)

`MAX` will return the highest value among the `FILTER`ed subset from Col C.

`VLOOKUP` will find that value in Col C and return the row.

The outer `FILTER` will filter in only that row from Col D.

`IFERROR` will return null if there is any error along the way.

The formula would also work with `INDEX` in place of the outer `FILTER`:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,VLOOKUP(MAX(FILTER(C:C,A:A=G2)),{C:C,ROW(C:C)},2,FALSE))))`

However, I prefer `FILTER` when I suspect there are unknown factors, since `FILTER` allows for further conditions to be added later.

Comment: Narek, if you would, please take a moment to click the checkmark for my post, which will select it as "Best Answer." This allows the contributor community here to see at a glance from the main listings page which posts have already been fully addressed. And it allows future site visitors to most easily find relevant answers.

Comment: Sure, done @Erik!

Comment: I just don't understand one thing. Why did you use ArrayFormula?

Comment: I tend to use `ArrayFormula( )` as a habit, even when included functions are themselves array functions, when I don't know the extended real-world use case of the user. As with using `FILTER` instead of `INDEX`, this allows the user more room to customize past what I've done. Having `ArrayFormula( )` won't hurt the formula as it is; but *without it*, the formula may break with future modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this calculation, simpler and apparently giving the same result **in the given situation**:

```
=iferror(Max(Filter(A2:D,A2:A=G2)),"")
```

Comment: Wow, right, this works too. But why both of you write IFERROR(, "")? Don't you like to see the error if there is an error? How it could be better to hide the ERROR?

Comment: I always try to hide predictable errors, such as the one that would have resulted from putting 5 as a "set value"

Comment: And BTW I don't think this solves the problem. It solves for only this particular case, where all larger numbers are concentrated in column D. If numbers in D column would be negative, for example, it would work wrong.

Comment: Why would I hide error. If 5 is out of range, then I would better see the error and know that I have set a wrong value, what you think?

Comment: It is always difficult to predict all possible cases of error.
You can avoid the IfError () during development ... but in the end I think it is better to use it, especially when, for example, you use the arrayformula () function

Answer (score 0):

give this a try too:

```
=iferror(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:D,A2:A=G2),3,0),1,4),"")
```

(after filtering the sheet based on the value of "set value", sorts the result based on column C in descending order and takes the fourth value of the first row)